# Facebook API - Top 5 users for engagement and likes on fb page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to construct a Top 5 of engaged users and users that liked something on my Facebook page(a non-profit)(for instance posts, links or images). It has to be an aggregated total of engagement and likes for all items on the page per user.

Can anybody provide with some clues as to which Facebook API calls I could use for this. At this moment I am only capable of determining which users liked the page, or a particular post.

If the question is too general or anything else, I'll gladly modify it. I would have liked to attach image for clarification, but is not a possibility for me yet due to reputation score.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to get all likes/comments/whatever from every single post with the API, store the numbers in your database and compare User IDs. You would have to keep it up to date too, so you would need to refresh your database entries from time to time.